# Using CakePHP's App::import() Function to Import Constant.php File

Tags: php, cakephp

Basically, I have a file called `Constants.php`, which is located in `/app/Lib/Constants.php`, and I want to use it in one of my Model classes (and possibly other classes that I've built). However, I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to do this (and CakePHP's documentation on [`App::import()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/file/Cake/Core/App.php#method-Appimport) is hard for me to understand).

How do I properly do this? Or is there another better convention of defining user-defined constants in CakePHP applications (besides using the Configure class)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Constants.php` file is one in which you are defining configuration variables for your application, I would suggest using the `Configure` class.

Place the `Constants.php` file into the `Config/` directory of your application.

In your `Config/bootstrap.php` you load the constants with the following line:

```
Configure::load('Constants');
```

Now, anywhere in your application you can read configuration information with the following:

```
Configure::read('Constants.Something');
```

Note, the Configure setup requires a particular format for your configuration variables. Use the following in your `Constants.php` file:

```
$config = array('Constants' => array(
    'Something' => 1234,
    'Foo' => 'Bar',
));
```

This is the recommended way to do configuration information, loaded in and made available to your entire application.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#including-files-with-app-import) is a better place to look as it explains it better :) All you have to do is this:

```
App::import('Lib', 'Constants');
```